# Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4 swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I am new to Xcode and mobile app. I am doing an app to find the current location. I tested it on the simulator and got this message in the console.
"Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4". What does it mean and how can I fix it?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
let regionRadius: Double = 1000

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    configureLocationServices()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func centerMapPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }
}
```

MKMapViewDelegate:

```
func centerMapOnUserLocation(){
guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else{return}
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius*2.0, regionRadius * 2.0 )
mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

}
```

CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
func configureLocationServices(){
    if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined{
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }else{
        return}
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    centerMapOnUserLocation()
}
```

Comment: Its just an internal message from the map view. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734831/mapkit-swift-4-xcode-9-2-could-not-inset-legal-attribution-from-corner-4 ?  Add the imports and delegates.

Answer (score 3):

this issue occurs when the required information in the right form is not found. if your device i trying to get some location or some number `a` variable, and that `a` variable is required for `afun`.. the value is not set into `a`, but `afun` is called that this error occurs..

call your cell's coordinates in `viewdidload` without any other function.

Here is the simplest way to get your cell's position. 
1. you should have updated privacies of the devices under infor.plist

Add following lines into your plist before closing  tag

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Privacy - Location Always Usage Description</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description</string>
```

after that.. this is the simplest working code .. i'm happily using it with no issue..

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class AddressVc: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

here is code to move map in center for the required location

```
    let latDelta:Double = 0.5
    let lngDelta:Double = 0.5

    let latitude:Double = 37.57554038
    let longitude:Double = -122.40068475

    let locationcoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let zoomSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lngDelta)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationcoordinates, span: zoomSpan)
    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

in the above code.. if you put device's lat and lng postions in latitude and lognitude that will move the map to your's devices's location.

now how to get device's location. 
here is the code you can put into your `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // device latitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    // device longitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
}
```

this is detect the device's latitude and longitude values. you can put them in above mentioned code..

Here is the full code.

---

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class AddressVc: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    devicelatitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    devicelongitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!



    let latDelta:Double = 0.5
    let lngDelta:Double = 0.5

    let latitude:Double = devicelatitude
    let longitude:Double = devicelongitude

    let locationcoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let zoomSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lngDelta)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationcoordinates, span: zoomSpan)
    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true) 
 }
```

I hope this will help you.. if not.. there would be many other who are facing this issue.

==========================

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me. The legal attribution error is being thrown before the `locationManager.delegate = self` line is executed.  I didn't see the legal attribution error until I started adding constraints.

Answer (score 0):

With the simulator open, go to the DEBUG menu on the mac top bar, the last option is location, mine was showing this error when set to NONE. Set it Custom Location, first with you prompt you to a custom location on a new window, fill that, close the simulator, and relaunch the app. It should get the custom location from your code now. (andrecasarini credit)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did what did you say, but I got the same message.what should I do?

Comment: You should just try to find an iphone and test in on the iphone. The error message is due to the simulator.

Comment: @AlexZansir that's incorrect, I'm testing on a device and still getting this message

Comment: I'm not using the simulator and am also seeing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the "Legal" link on the bottom left of the MapView is not within bounds or is obscured. There are similar errors for the map's scale and for the compass that appears when rotating.

Consider using size constraints or a `safeAreaInset`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the legal inset bug is in Apple's mapkit initialization code and unrelated to what we do when we use the code.  Here's my reasoning.

If you use storyboards and the UIMapKit drag and drop module, the legal inset error pops up somewhere between the call to the initial call to **application** in the app delegate and the first **viewDidLoad** call, i.e., it's an OS error.

I got curious if I could work around it and wrote a version that doesn't use the storyboard editor. I was thinking that perhaps the editor was inserting some broken code into the app.  My test app has two views, the start view and a second view with the map on it.  The code is shown below. Don't be harsh, it's my first attempt at understanding what's going on with controllers views and subviews using programmatic views and subviews. It isn't pretty but it works to isolate the legal inset bug.

I started by building a new xcode project and deleting the storyboard. I then replaced the **application** function stub in appdelegate with the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
 launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let viewController = ViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let mapView = mapViewController()
    mapView.otherView = viewController
    viewController.mapView = mapView
    return true
}
```

Even though the mapView is created here, the legal inset error doesn't show up. What **does** show up are a couple of other messages about scale and compass having some sort of issue. Since I was focusing on the legal inset bug, I ignored them and moved on.

I then replaced the default view controller with code that created two subviews, one a subview that serves as a button to switch to the second view controller and the second subview that serves as "you're on the first view" marker view.  That required figuring out how to handle a tap. The color changing code in the tap handler was initial "hello world. I see a tap" code and serves no other purpose.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let DynamicView = UIView()
let switchView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:  UIScreen.main.bounds.minX+10, y:  UIScreen.main.bounds.minY+20, width: 40, height: 40))
public var mapView:mapViewController? = nil
public var otherView:UIViewController? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

    DynamicView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    DynamicView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    switchView.backgroundColor = .orange
    switchView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    var gR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlebigTap(_:)))
    DynamicView.addGestureRecognizer(gR)
    gR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlesmallTap(_:)))
    switchView.addGestureRecognizer(gR)
    self.view.addSubview(switchView)
    self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)

    DynamicView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    DynamicView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    DynamicView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    DynamicView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    DynamicView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 110).isActive = true

}
@objc func handlebigTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if ( self.DynamicView.backgroundColor == .green){
        self.DynamicView.backgroundColor = .blue
    } else {
        self.DynamicView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
@objc func handlesmallTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if ( self.switchView.backgroundColor == .orange){
        self.switchView.backgroundColor = .blue
        present(mapView!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.switchView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

At this point, I checked to see if the first call to **viewDidLoad** triggered the legal inset error and saw that it did not. That meant the error was being triggered somewhere in the mapKit initialization code which was yet to be built. I simply copied and pasted the first viewController into a new file and called that mapViewController. I commented out the DynamicView code left over from the first controller and added the mapKit initialization code as shown here:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class mapViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {


let DynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:  UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX-110, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY-110, width: 100, height: 100))
let switchView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:  UIScreen.main.bounds.minX+10, y:  UIScreen.main.bounds.minY+20, width: 40, height: 40))
var mapView = MKMapView()
public var otherView:UIViewController? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

 // DynamicView.backgroundColor = .yellow
 // DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
 // DynamicView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    switchView.backgroundColor = .orange
    switchView.layer.borderWidth = 2

    var gR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlebigTap(_:)))
    DynamicView.addGestureRecognizer(gR)
     gR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlesmallTap(_:)))
    switchView.addGestureRecognizer(gR)
    self.view.addSubview(switchView)
 // self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)


 // mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 60, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 300)

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = true

    view.addSubview(mapView)
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true
    mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true


}
@objc func handlebigTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if ( self.DynamicView.backgroundColor == .green){
        self.DynamicView.backgroundColor = .blue
    } else {
        self.DynamicView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
@objc func handlesmallTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if ( self.switchView.backgroundColor == .orange){
        self.switchView.backgroundColor = .blue
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.switchView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)



}
```

}

I ran the above code and stepped through looking for the legal inset message to show up. This is the offending line:

mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 60, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 300)

As soon as the view is framed, the error message comes out. Doesn't matter what dimensions you give the view, the message appears. OK.... Maybe the message expects a constraint based framing instead of hard coded per the offending line.

I commented out the line and added constraints to the view and still the error popped up.

At this point I gave up. I couldn't figure out how to configure a map view so the error message doesn't show up. Hopefully Apple will pipe up and say something at this point or someone else will pick up the baton to see if there's a way to configure mapkit to stop spewing error messages.

As for myself at least I learned how to dynamically add views, subviews, gesture recognizers and constraints so my time was profitably spent chasing the bug. Thanks to all who posted sample dynamic view code, gesture recognition code, subview code and constraint code. You may recognize a bit of your code here.

Answer (score -7):

You have not typed in an opening curly bracket for your MapVC Class:

your code:

```
class MapVC: UIViewController
```

to fix:

```
class MapVC: UIViewController {
```

Comment: This can't be the issue, as the compiler would complain and the user would not be able to actually run the code