# can't show map annotation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am trying to add map annotation, but when i try to run the app, the map annotation doesnt show, and give error message.

> Add Map Annotation[3668:68848] Could not inset legal attribution from
>   corner 4

actually I just follow along a tutorial on Youtube in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRextIKJCnI , in swift3 this code seems work, but I don't know why it doesnt work in me. I am using swift 4 and Xcode 9.2

I have tried a solution from stack overflow but it doesn't work in me, in here [Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4 swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223316/could-not-inset-legal-attribution-from-corner-4-swift?rq=1)

What went wrong in here?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapKitView: MKMapView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
        let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-6.239116, 106.789415)
        let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation =  MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "My Shop"
        annotation.subtitle = "Come visit here"
        mapKitView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
    let annotation =  MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "My Shop"
    annotation.subtitle = "Come visit here"
    mapKitView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

And that's *all* you're saying. But... That annotation has no `coordinate`! So how do you imagine the map can possibly know where it's supposed to go?