# MapKit (Swift 4) Xcode 9.2 - 'Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mapkit, xcode9.2

I'm doing a project that deals with a MapKit. My issue is when I run the app, I get the 'Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4.' error. What solution can I take to resolve this issue?

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw7rk.png)

[My app screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPIAo.png)

Comment: Ignore it. It is an internal debugging message from the mapView around placing the "legal" link ta the bottom of the map.

Comment: How do I get my app running right? Do I need to comment out something in my code?

Comment: You haven’t explained what your problem is. This message doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: My map doesn't display when I run it on the simulator. My blue location dot shows up, but my map doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error as you - the map was not showing up and I was getting the error:

2018-08-25 09:59:17.324966-0400 Parse Foursquare Clone[45537:42276733] Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4

2018-08-25 09:59:17.332612-0400 Parse Foursquare Clone[45537:42276733] Could not inset scale from edge 9

The reason is because I did not setup the delegates, MKMapViewDelegate and CLLocationManagerDelegate. Here is what I'm looking at in case you're confused. Once I set these up, the map started appearing. Hope this helps!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class locationVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

Comment: Yes. Worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Re-edit the info.plist file.  Open As -> Source Code To show the XML format of info.plist

Your xCode error message may say the the "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" or "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" has problem.

COPY the "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" (or "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription") in error console and PASTE to the info.plist source file.

Save the info.plist and run it again.

I do it this way and resolved my problem

Comment: This is not what is causing the inset legal attribution error. I can reproduce the error and have NSLocationWhenInUseDescription set properly.